# Where to set the Bing Map Key in NMF file?

Tags: bing-maps, arcpad

Where do I have to set the Bing Map Key in my NMF file?

> At ArcPad 10.2, the ability to browse for Bing Map services in the Add Data from Server dialog box was removed. The Bing Map NMF files are included in the Sample directory (\Shared Documents\ArcPad\Samples\Bing Maps). Use the Add Layer(s) tool to add any of these NMF files to your ArcPad map. With an NMF file in your map, your Bing Key entered in ArcPad Options, and an active network connection, ArcPad will automatically download the Bing Map tiles for your map extent.

Source: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcpad/10.2/app/index.html#//00s10000015z000000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay found it, ArcPad options really mean ArcPad options! I thought I can set the key into the NMF file.

[image]

---

If you don't want to enter the key manually in your Mobile Device you can set the **`<SERVER>`** tag right at the end before **`</PREFERENCES>`** in the **ArcPadPref.apx** file:

```xml
<SERVER url="" username="" password="" bingkey="XXX"/>
```

*Just replace XXX with your key.*