# Using Bing Map via NMF file in 2017 in ArcPad 10.2

Tags: mobile, bing-maps, arcpad

Does anybody has recently experiences with using Bing Map Service on an Handheld Device with ArcPad 10.2?

I'm getting the Error message:

> **Error**
>
> Missing AuthenticationResultCode in response from Bing server

[image: arcpad screenshot]

*The Bing Map key I have set as described [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/191128/).*